# C# Interface Contraints

Tags: c#, generics

I am experimenting with Generic Constraints.  When declaring a constraint on a class as so:

```
    public class DocumentPrinter<T> where T : IFooDoc
```

I am able to access method declared by IFooDoc within the methods of the DocumentPrinter class. However, if I make DocumentPrinter implement an interface that declares the contraint, eg:

```
public interface IDocumentPrinter<T> where T : IFooDoc
{
    void Add(T fooDoc);
    void PrintFoos();
}
```

and then declare DocumentPrinter as so:

```
   public class DocumentPrinter<T>: IDocumentPrinter<T>
```

properties/methods of IFooDoc instances are no longer available within the methods of the Document printer. It seems that I must explicitly declare an interface constraint upon the class itself if I am to access members declared by the type.

Do I understand this correctly or is it possible to declare the constraint on the interface and to have that constraint realized by the class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do I understand this correctly or is it possible to declare the constraint on the interface and to have that constraint realized by the class?

Correct. You *have*<sup>1</sup> to declare the constraint on the type parameters for the generic class as well. Just because you named the type parameter in `DocumentPrinter<T>` to have the same name as the type parameter in `IDocumentPrinter<T>` does not mean that they are the same types. When you declare

```
public class DocumentPrinter<T> : IDocumentPrinter<T>
```

you are in fact saying to use `T` that parameterizes `DocumentPrinter<T>` to parameterize `IDocumentPrinter<T>` and *now* they are the same types. But for that to be legal, `T` from `DocumentPrinter<T>` has to satisfy all constraints on the type parameter for `IDocumentPrinter<T>`. Thus, you must explicitly say that `T` satisfies `T : IFooDoc`.

<sup>1</sup>: Apparently I need to state this explicitly. If you don't do something the language specification requires you to do, your code won't compile. The language specification requires that when you parameterize a generic type, the type that you parameterize it with must satisfy all the constraints on that type parameter for that generic type. If you do not, your code won't compile.

Comment: This is misleading, you don't have to add the constraint to the class to be able to access the members, you have to add it for the code to compile.

Comment: @svick: The question as stated is "*Do I understand this correctly or is it possible to declare the constraint on the interface and to have that constraint realized by the class?*" Not sure how my answer is misleading. If you *have to declare the constraint* as I specified on my answer, there is an implicit *if you don't, the code won't compile* since any time you do not do something that language *requires* you to do, you have code that won't compile. But again, the question was *do I have to do this, or is there a way to do it without being explicit.* I answered that question. Downovting?

Comment: The question says: “It seems that I must explicitly declare an interface constraint upon the class itself *if I am to access members declared by the type*.” To me, that indicates that the OP *doesn't realize the code won't compile*. That's why I think it's important to stress that out.

Comment: @svick: I give the OP more credit than that. It's generally pretty obvious using an IDE or a command-line compiler when code won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

> properties/methods of IFooDoc instances are no longer available within the methods of the Document printer

Well, it's kind of irrelevant what IntelliSense tells you **when your code doesn't compile**.

If you want to implement `IDocumentPrinter<T>`, you **have to** satisfy its constraint. If you don't, your code won't compile.